# Help proving $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{1}^{5} f(x+h)dx = \int_{1}^{5}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Suppose a function $f$ is integrable on $[0,6]$. Prove that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{1}^{5} f(x+h)dx = \int_{1}^{5}f(x)dx$$

This seems like the easiest thing, I would normally just bring the limit inside the integral and evaluate $f(x+h)$ to $f(x)$, but its asking to prove that this is the case and I haven't even used the fact that its integrable on $[0,6]$. I tried the epsilon delta proof this way. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and assume

$$\left|\int_{1}^{5}f(x+h)dx - \int_{1}^{5}f(x)dx\right| < \epsilon$$

I tried to find a $\delta$ so that $|f(x+h)-f(x)| < \delta$, but had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! For a hint: how are you justifying being able to bring the limit inside the integral?

Comment: Is it helpful to change the left hand side to $\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{1+h}^{5+h}f(x)\ dx$?

Answer (score 2):

$\int_1^{5}f(x+h)dx=\int_{1+h}^{5+h}f(x)dx=\int_1^5f(x)dx-\int_1^{1+h}f(x)dx+\int_{5}^{5+h}f(x)dx$

Since $F(x)=\int_1^xf(x)dx$ is a continuous function we have that $\lim_{h\to0}\int_a^{a+h}f(x)dx=\lim_{h\to 0} F(a+h)-F(a)=0$

So when we pass to the limit we have that
$$\lim_{h\to0}\int_1^{5}f(x+h)dx=\lim_{h\to0}\int_1^5f(x)dx-\int_1^{1+h}f(x)dx+\int_{5}^{5+h}f(x)dx=\int_1^5f(x)dx$$